# How to change border a lable when focusout in Jquery

Tags: jquery, focus

I have a list of images.

```
<div class="modal-body" id='myModalImageContent'>
   @foreach (var image in ViewBag.images)
   {
   <label title="@image" id="imageItem" class="imageItem" data-url="@image">
    <img src="@Url.Content(image)" alt="@image" width="110" height="140">
   </label>
   }
</div>
```

I have a JQuery to make it border when an image is selected=> it's ok. But now I want to remove border when it lost focus, I use follow code, but it doesn't work.
Do anyone know how to fix it?

```
$('.imageItem').click(function() {
    var $itemClicked = $(this);
    url = $itemClicked.attr('data-url');
    urlImage = url.substr(1);
    $(this).addClass('isClicked');
    $(this).blur(function() {
        alert('Bye');
        $(this).removeClass("isClicked");
        $(this).addClass('lossFocus');
    });
})
// When loss focus
$('.imageItem').focusout(function() { // I also tried with .blur               
    alert('Bye');
    $(this).removeClass("isClicked");
    $(this).addClass('lossFocus');
});
```

**Update** What I mean is when I select an image, this image is bolder, and I want when I select another image, the first image will hide border, and second image is how border.

Current the issue I face now as below picture:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You may use `hover` with `toggleClass` .

```js
$('.imageItem').click(function() {
 $(this).addClass('isClicked');
  $(this).hover(
    function() {
      $(this).toggleClass('isClicked lossFocus');
    }
  );
});
```

```css
.isClicked {
  background-color: lightblue;
}

.lossFocus {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label title="@image" id="imageItem" class="imageItem" data-url="@image">
Image tag
</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('.imageItem').click(function() {
 $(this).toggleClass('clicked');
});
```

```css
label{
 width:200px;
 height:200px;
}
.clicked {
  background-color: blue;
   border:4px blue solid;
     display: block;
}
.clicked:hover {
  background-color: red;
   border:4px red solid;
     display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
<label title="@image" id="imageItem" class="imageItem" data-url="@image">

<img src="https://picsum.photos/200/200?random"/>
</label>
</div>
```

Create a CSS class with hover effect and toggle that class to the element where you required.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved.
I add the title for image that click, then when click another image, I find the  with title ==> set css to remove border.

```
        $('.imageItem').click(function () {                
            url = $(this).attr('data-url');
            urlImage = url.substr(1);             
            $(this).attr('title', 'preimage')
            $(this).toggleClass('clicked');

        })
        $('img').click(function () {               
            $('[title="preimage"]').css('border', 'none');
        })
```